# Complex Contour Integral with tan z

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I would like to compute the below integral $$I = \int_{S_n}\frac{1}{z + \tan{z} - i}dz$$ where $S_n$ is the square with vertices $n\pi(1+i), n\pi(1-i), n\pi(-1+i), n\pi(-1-i)$. If we consider $f(z) = z + \tan{z} - i$, we can see that $f$ has simple routes $z_n$ only, hence $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ has simple poles only. Therefore: $$I = 2{\pi}i\sum_{z_n}\operatorname{Res}(f,z_n) = 2{\pi}i\sum_{z_n}\frac{1}{f'(z)}$$

Could you help with the rest of the solution, or even correct my thought if not correct?

Comment: Quick tip: use `\operatorname{}` when typing in "Res".

Comment: Correct, all $z_n$ are simple and $\pi/2 + \pi n$ are removable singularities. The residue at $z_n$ is
$$\frac 1 {\tan^2 z_n + 2} =
\frac 1 {(z_n - i)^2 + 2}.$$

Comment: I saw in another post related to this integral, that $\tan z$ is uniformly bounded on $S_{n}$ and hence $\frac{1}{z + \tan z - i} - \frac{1}{z}$ is of order $O(\frac{1}{z^2})$, but I am not sure why this holds true. Would you have any idea?