# Laurent Series of $\frac{1}{z + \tan z -i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I want to calculate the Laurent series of $$\frac{1}{z + \tan z -i}$$ around the poles of the denominator, i.e.: the roots of $z + \tan z - i = 0$. Would you know how to proceed with it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be helpful, but the quantity $\tan z - i$ is never $0$

Comment: Correct, but the denominator is $z + \tan z - i$ which according to Wolfram has exactly(?) one complex root.

Comment: That's what I mean by the never zero part comes in. For example, woukd it still only have one pole if it were -2i instead?

Comment: If you put it into the Wolfram solver you will still get a solution for -2i, hence I think $z + \tan z - i = 0$ does have a solution.

Comment: You've already worked out the $(z - z_n)^{-1}$ term [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4016411). The reciprocal of a power series $\sum_{n \geq 1} c_n z^n$ with $c_1 \neq 0$ is $z^{-1}/c_1 - c_2/c_1^2 + \ldots \,$. The general term (starting with $n = 0$) is given by Faa di Bruno's formula:
$$[z^n] \left( \sum_{n \geq 1} c_n z^n \right)^{-1} =
\frac 1 {(n + 1)!} \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n + 1}
 \frac {(-1)^k k!} {c_1^{k + 1}}
 B_{n + 1, k}(1! c_2, \ldots, (n - k + 2)! c_{n - k + 3}).$$